# Path from process name that is NOT running

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I want to get full path from process name WITHOUT running the process.In otherwords- where C# gets absolute path when it is executing following :

Process.Start(startInfo);

startInfo does not contain absolute path.

Comment: So you just want the C# equivalent of the `WHERE` command?

Comment: eg: I know process name abc.exe. I want to know its absolute path. But dont want to run it.

Comment: You could use `Process.Start` to execute the Windows `WHERE` command, and read the output.

Answer (score 2):

The full path of the executable is resolved through the %PATH% environment variable. You can replicate the behaviour as follows:

```
var result = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
                        .Split(';')
                        .Select(path => Path.Combine(path, "notepad.exe"))
                        .FirstOrDefault(path => File.Exists(path));

// result == "C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: You also have to check the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Uses standard windows search policy: current folder and folders in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood, but what about :

```
var fInfo = new FileInfo(startInfo.FileName);
var fullPath = fInfo.FullName;
```

?

Comment: I know process name abc.exe. I want to know its absolute path. But dont want to run it.